# How to print through remote computer with TeamViewer

Tags: printing, teamviewer

We are using TeamViewer and we would like to print at the remote computer. Is this possible? If yes, how?

I've been reading the docs but I can't find a solution.

Further Explanation:

I am on my machine say machine 1. And, I am connected to Machine 2 on the internet somewhere through Teamviewer.

I know that Machine 2 has printer attached to it and it is working well.

What I want is to print a Word Document for example which is locally on Machine 1 to be printed on Machine 2's printer. Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't that deafult behavior? You don't really start a session on the remote computer, you just view it's screen. Therefore, all printing commands will be at the remote computer. Or did you mean the other way around? Print at the remote computer to a printer at your side? A.f.a.i.k. that's not possible.

Comment: Well if you have total control of Machine 2, just transfer the file from Machine 1 to Machine 2, print it and delete the file if needed.

Comment: Comment by ihightower: @Rhyuk. I have complete control of Machine 2 and I understand that transferring the file works.. But, is there a permanent way to set up Machine 1 and Machine 2 through Teamviewer in such a fashion that "no manual transfer of files are required"...

All I would like to do is select the file in Machine1 for example... and Click Print and the printer will be something like.. print to "Teamviewer Machine 2 - Printer 1".. and all the background transfer or whatever required happens automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Teamviewer VPN to connect the two systems and use the File and Printer Sharing.

You have to share the Printer on Machine 2 and make sure the user from Machine 1 has access to this network share. Then connect the shared printer from Machine 2 on Machine 1 via Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Google Cloudprint.  Especially fantastic if you are already have a Gmail, google accounts, youtube, chrome all linked together.

I just tried it myself today, was looking for the teamviewer solution to print... but no luck.

anyways, just check out http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn
and install one of the apps for the PC to allow sharing printers

Answer (score 1):

To activate the remote printing function, follow these steps:

1. In the Remote Control window, click Extras | Remote printing during a session.
    The TeamViewer printing dialog box will open.
2. Click the Continue button.
    On the remote computer, the TeamViewer print driver will be installed. This only has to be done once.
3. You have now successfully activated remote printing. All printers available on the local computer can be used by the remote computer, too.

Once TeamViewer remote printing has been activated, the printers available to the local computer can be selected in the print dialog boxes and control panel on the remote computer. TeamViewer remote printing printers are labeled with via TeamViewer.

To run a print job, follow these steps:

1. Open the document you would like to print on the remote computer.
2. Open the Print dialog box.
3. Select a printer ending with via TeamViewer.
4. Start the print job.
5. The document will print out on the selected printer at the local computer

This is from the Teamviewer 8 Manual

Comment: I believe the OP asked for the opposite, i.e., printing a local document on the remote printer.