# Set Teamviewer Remote Printer as Default

Tags: remote-desktop, printing, printer, steam

I am using TeamViewer, and need to print something from the remote computer to the local printer to which the computer I am actually on is attached. The thing that I am trying to print does not give me the option to select an alternative printer, and just assumes the default printer. How can I change the TeamViewer remote printer to the default so that it will print normally? When I check the devices and printers list, the printer is not listed.

Comment: what version of teamviewer? latest (v9)?

Comment: @Logman Yes, version 9.

Comment: activate the remote printing function? http://superuser.com/questions/432783/how-to-print-through-remote-computer-with-teamviewer

Comment: @Logman Already did that.

Comment: Did you try this-
open device and printer,right click on your printer which you wanna set as default,then click "Set as default printer"

Comment: @SSAURABHH The `Devices` window does not list printers that are connected via TeamViewer.